# "Please add a @NgModule annotation" error... on something that has @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-aot

I've found other posts on this subject, but my issues aren't the same. I can avoid this issue entirely by turning off AOT compilation.

I'm using Angular 11.

In code that had been working before Angular 11, I had some providers defined like this:

```
  providers: [
    HighlighterService,
    SignInService,
    { provide: AUTHENTICATOR, useClass: AuthenticationService },
    { provide: NETWORK_ERROR_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG, useFactory: getNetworkErrorInterceptorConfig },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: UnauthorizedNetworkInterceptor, multi: true },
  ],
```

With AOT in Angular 11, this provider setup fails with:

> Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'InjectionToken' was called in 'AUTHENTICATOR'

The supposed solution I've found for this issue by researching the above error is this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule...
    MyOtherModule // <--- New problem crops up here
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<any> {
    return {
      ngModule: AppModule,
      providers: [
        HighlighterService,
        SignInService,
        { provide: AUTHENTICATOR, useClass: AuthenticationService },
        { provide: NETWORK_ERROR_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG, useFactory: getNetworkErrorInterceptorConfig },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: UnauthorizedNetworkInterceptor, multi: true },
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

The above changes, however, just spawn a new problem. A module that I was able to import before without any difficultly now produces this run-time error:

> Error: Unexpected value 'MyOtherModule in C:/...' imported by the module 'AppModule in C:...'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

But `MyOtherModule` does have `@NgModule` annotation. Always had it, and never before was there any such error about `@NgModule` annotation not being there.

The only thing I can think of is that something about the order in which Angular is trying to resolve modules references `MyModule` before the `@NgModule` annotation has been executed on the class.

If that's the problem, I have no idea how to solve it.

If that's not the problem, I'm even more mystified about how to get my code working properly with AOT.

**UPDATE**

I understand the problem better now, but I still don't know what to do about it.

The `@NgModule` annotation adds this static member to a module class:

```
export class MyModule {
  public static ngModuleDef = defineNgModule({
    type: MyModule ,
    imports: [...my imports...],
    declarations: [...my declarations...],
    bootstrap: [...my bootstrap component, if any...]
  });
```

In the Angular code base, I found a place where a function is called `getNgModuleDef(moduleType)`, and the above error about the missing @NgModule annotation is thrown if no module definition is found.

From this I can conclude that `MyOtherModule` is being referenced before the annotation has had a chance to act on the `MyOtherModule` and inject this static `ngModuleDef` member, and therefore my module has not been defined as a valid module.

This seems like a nasty Catch-22 to me.

Is there someway to delay the instantiation of my main `AppModule` until I'm sure `MyOtherModule` has been fully loaded and defined by @NgModule?

Comment: Hi. Can you show declaration of `AUTHENTICATOR` token?

Comment: `export const AUTHENTICATOR = new InjectionToken<Authenticator>('authenticator');`